# How to use the AJAX response in FLUID templates TYPO3 Extbase

Tags: ajax, typo3, fluid, extbase

I finally made my AJAX working in Extbase Typo3 6. However, I'm trying to use the returned array from AJAX in my FLUID view.

my Ajax action in Controller:

```
public function ajaxAction(){
    $id = $this->request->getArgument['id'];
    $record = $this->articleRepository->findByUid($id);
    return json_encode(['record'=>$record,'status' => 'Loaded']);
}
```

My AJAX :

```
function dropCall(selectFieldObj) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.status);
        }
    });

}
```

Now the question is how do I use the `data object` sent from the controller action in my View ? The alert is being displayed.

My `List.html` view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link
            = '<f:uri.action action="ajax" controller="Article" pageType="99" arguments="{data:1}"/>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fileadmin/myScript.js"></script>

<select id="drop" onchange="dropCall(this)">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
    <option value="3">Grape</option>
</select>
```

In my view, I should be able to do something like

```
  <h1> {record.name} </h1>
```

**EDIT**

The object `record` might contain many properties and each `record.property` like `record.name` will be under `<h1>` tags and `record.somethingelse` can be under some under tag.

Just like we send `objects` from `controller` to `view` and use them in FLUID, I would want to do the same with AJAX

Comment: Is you question about how to iterate over `data.record.whatever`, create new `<option>s` and update the select box with jQuery/javascript or did I miss something?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not my aim. Check my edit please. Thank You :)

Comment: Ok, but that's not much difference actually. The model is already there (`data.record`), the view is the html which is already in the browser and the controller, well, you have to code some JavaScript I guess (`jQuery("#myH1").html(record.name)` and so on). If you want to make this a little bit easier, you can use a JS MVC-like helper like [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This would work if I were to give a `single record`, but what if I have `multiple records` in `record` contains all the DB Table, that's not very effeceint.. or is it? I dont know

Comment: Ok, then just return the data you need in the extbase controller, not the whole database content. And also, do not read just one record, but all you need from the database with `->findALl()` or a custom method on the repository.